# How to enable fontWeights with custom fonts react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts

I have a React Native App v .66.1 - And I have my custom fonts loaded and they are working for both iOS and Android. However, I cannot use the fontWeight property to bold them. Is there a step I'm missing?

My font structure:

```
root/src/assets/fonts/[fonts are here]
```

react-native.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  assets: [
    './src/assets/fonts'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Font weight does not always work properly on Android. I'd recommend using different files for Regular and Bold variations, like:

- FontName-Regular.ttf
- FontName-Bold.ttf

Don't forget to link them using `react-native link`

Then use the appropriate fontFamily on your regular or bold text.

Comment: How would you specify the weight for a variable font?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `react-native.config.js` file like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    project: {    //maybe you're forgetting this
        ios: {},
        android: {},
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts']
};
```

After this, link your assets using the `react-native link` cmd.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: The fonts load, though. It is just the weight property that I can't use (I know you can't use 'bold' with android, but my research led me to believe that you can use the numerical values like '800' instead).